# Cómo extraer un número de un arreglo

Tags: c

Necesito obtener el número de un arreglo. Por ej tengo char fila[3]="1A"; quiero el 1. Se me ocurrió esto pero no funciona.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char fila[3]="1A"; int columna;
int buscar_numero(fila){
    for(int x=0;x<=strlen(fila);x++){
        if(isdigit(fila[x])!=0){
            return fila[x];
        }
    }
}
```

por lo que el retorno de la función debería ser = 1.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es exactamente el problema?

Comment: No lo consigo con ese código, la parte que falla es la del isdigit, donde debería revisar el espacio del arreglo y decirme si es un digito o no

Comment: Entonces muestra la parte del isdigit que armaste

Comment: está en el código

Comment: Sorry, desconocimiento de funciones de librerías, ya lo veo

Comment: "No lo consigo" no da mucha información. ¿Qué error te da? ¿Un problema de compilación (cuál), un problema de ejecución (qué datos usas, qué error te sale), un valor incorrecto (qué datos usas, qué valor esperas, qué valor obtienes)?.

Answer (score 1):

Yo y mi desconocimiento de algunas funciones de librerías xd, sería algo así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char fila[3]="1A"; int columna, caracter;
int buscar_numero(fila){
    // No tiene que ser menor igual al largo, recuerda que siempre retorna 1 mas, si es "1A" retornara 2, pero la cadena empieza desde 0
    for(int x=0;x<strlen(fila);x++){ 
        caracter=fila[x]; // Tomo el valor entero del caracter
        if(isdigit(caracter)!=0){
            return fila[x]; // Retorna el caracter
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que le tienes que pasar, es el valor entero del caracter, la declaración la cito:

> Declaration Following is the declaration for isdigit() function.
>
> int isdigit(int c);